# Unwrapping a 'String?' variable in swift?

Tags: swift

**I get an error saying:**

Playground execution failed:

> error: myfirstplayground.playground:21:19: error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
>   var dateNum = Int(dates)

**Here is my code:**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import Foundation


class FartsPerDate {

    var dates: Int = 0
    farts: Int = 0

    init( dateNum: Int ) {

        self.dates = dateNum
        self.fpd()
    }

    func fpd() -> Int {

        farts = Int( (dates - 1)/2 )
        return farts
    }
}

print("Which date is it? (Enter an integer): >")
var dates = readLine()
var dateNum = Int(dates)
var answer = FartsPerDate(dateNum: dateNum! )
print(answer)
```

Comment: what is the return type of realLine() ?

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for Int that takes a string (`init(_:radix:)`) is "failable". That means that if you pass it a string that can't be converted to an `Int`, it will return nil.

It sounds like the `String` you are starting from is also an Optional, so you need to unwrap the string and also unwrap the resulting Int:

You should look up "optional binding" and guard statements, which are 2 ways to deal with optionals:

Optional binding

```
if let datesString = dates, 
     let var dateNum = Int(datesString) {
   var answer = FartsPerDate(dateNum: dateNum )
   print(answer)
} else {
  print("You did not enter a valid number")
}
```

Or using a guard statement:

```
guard let datesString = dates, 
    let var dateNum = Int(dates) else {
  //Normally you'd use a return here but you are not inside a function so you have to
  //exit the entire playground
  fatalError("You did not enter a valid number")  
}
var answer = FartsPerDate(dateNum: dateNum )
print(answer)
```

Dealing with optionals is something EVERY Swift programmer has to come to terms with. I suggest you download the Apple iBook "The Swift Programming Language" and read the section on optionals, and then do a bunch of exercises using them until you are comfortable.